# Adjusting an instant-rice recipe for regular rice

Tags: substitutions, rice

I'm trying a [very simple beans-and-rice recipe](http://allrecipes.com/recipe/quick-black-beans-and-rice/), but I noticed it calls for instant brown rice, and I'm using regular.

The recipe has me cooking the rice within a quick sauce (tomato, black beans, seasoning), but I'm worried (albeit with no actual specific foundation) that the sauce might not work well under a much longer cooking time. Whereas stirring it in mid-cooking sounds like a Not Good Thing for rice.

Do I need to do anything special to make this substitution work?

Answer (score 5):

Instant rice is just parboiled rice made to cook faster. Since brown rice takes a significantly longer time to cook than minute rice, you might try cooking your rice first until its 1/2 to 2/3 done, then transfer it to the sauce to finish cooking and absorb the flavor.

Answer (score 3):

That "sauce" should work fine with a longer cooking time. I'd just go for it.

If you want to be careful, it should also be fine to cook the rice partially, with the seasonings and any liquid from the original recipe, and then stir in the rest for the remaining cooking.